# imePadding() is not working in compose when the keyboard is opened

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a login screen and I want to move the screen up by opening the keyboard and setting the login button on the top of the keyboard when it is opened. I added a padding at the bottom of the screen but it's not working too.

```
 Column(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {

                    TitleText(
                        text = stringResource(R.string.join_us_to_start_searching),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                    )
                    LightContentText(
                        text = stringResource(R.string.you_can_search_c_ourse_apply_course_and_find_scholarship_for_abroad_studies),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50 .dp))
                    MiddleSection(
                        modifier = modifier.imePadding(),
                        state = state,
                        onShowSnackbar = { message, undoText ->
                            onShowSnackbar(
                                message,
                                undoText
                            )
                        },
                        onStartTimer = {viewModel.updateStartTimerInState(it)},
                        onMobileNumber = {viewModel.updateMobileNumberInState(it)},
                        onClickVerify = {
                            viewModel.verifyCode(state.mobileNumber)
                        },
                        onClickLogin = { phone, otp ->
                            viewModel.login(
                                mobileNumber = state.mobileNumber,
                                code = otp
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
```

```
@Composable
internal fun MiddleSection(
    modifier: Modifier,
    state: LoginUiState.Data,
    onShowSnackbar: suspend (message: String, undoText: String?) -> Boolean,
    onStartTimer: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    onMobileNumber: (phone: String) -> Unit,
    onClickVerify: () -> Unit,
    onClickLogin: (phone: String, otp: Int) -> Unit,
) {

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val resend = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val (otpValue, otpUpdate) = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(26.dp)
    ) {
        CoralBasicTextField(
            value = state.mobileNumber,
            modifier = modifier.clearFocusOnKeyboardDismiss(),
            updateTextValue = {
                if (it.length <= 12) {
                    onMobileNumber(it)
                    if (state.mobileNumber.length + 1 == 12) {
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                        onStartTimer(true)
                    }
                }
            },
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done, keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone),
            placeholder = stringResource(R.string.mobile_number),
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = CoralIcons.Phone,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.phone),
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
                )
            }) {

        }
        CoralBasicTextField(
            modifier = modifier.clearFocusOnKeyboardDismiss(),
            readOnly = state.mobileNumber.length != 11 && state.result == null,
            value = otpValue,
            updateTextValue = { otpUpdate(it) },
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done, keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            placeholder = stringResource(R.string.code),
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = CoralIcons.Lock,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.code),
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
                )
            }) {

        }
        Box(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
        ) {
            if (resend.value) {
                MediumContentText(
                    modifier = modifier.clickable {
                        onStartTimer(true)
                        resend.value = false
                        otpUpdate("")
                        onClickVerify()
                    },
                    text = stringResource(R.string.resend_code),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                )
            } else {
                Countdown(
                    targetTime = 180000,
                    startTimer = state.startTime,
                    onFinished = {
                        onStartTimer(false)
                        resend.value = true
                    }) { time ->
                    MediumContentText(
                        text = time,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 32.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            CoralButton(
                modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                enabled = state.result != null,
                onClick = {
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                    if (state.mobileNumber.isEmpty() || otpValue.isEmpty()) {
                        scope.launch {
                            onShowSnackbar(
                                context.getString(R.string.please_enter_your_mobile_number_and_otp_code),
                                ""
                            )
                        }
                        return@CoralButton
                    }
                    scope.launch {
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                        onClickLogin(state.mobileNumber, otpValue.trim().toInt())
                    }
                }) {
                LightContentText(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .weight(1f),
                    text = stringResource(R.string.login),
                    style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontSize = 14.sp)
                )
            }
        }
      
    }
}
```

when i remove this part of the code:

```
  TitleText(
                        text = stringResource(R.string.join_us_to_start_searching),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                    )
                    LightContentText(
                        text = stringResource(R.string.you_can_search_c_ourse_apply_course_and_find_scholarship_for_abroad_studies),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50 .dp))
```

everything is fine but otherwise is not.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? What happens if you only remove the Spacer?

Comment: I mean the login button is behind of keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Please try to wrap your `Text` Composables and your `Spacer` into a separate Column and apply a `weight`:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
) {     
    TitleText(
        text = stringResource(R.string.join_us_to_start_searching),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
    )
    LightContentText(
        text = stringResource(R.string.you_can_search),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
}
```

By that approach, the `MiddleSection` Composable including the optional `imePadding` will be measured first as it has no `weight` set. Afterwards, the other Composables will take up the remaining space.

Please let me know if that approach changes anything.

Comment: It works but TitleText and LightContentText are not showing

Comment: Are they not showing all the time or are they only not showing when the keyboard is opened? If it's not showing when the keyboard is openend, then this is because your screen might not have enough space to display all content above the keyboard. Usually, you use `imePadding` with something like a LazyColumn, that can be shrinked easily wihout any content being pushed off.